# cp linux command options

Tags: linux, cp

how i do i copy all files from dir to another dir and escape file already exist and not overwrite it  , using cp command under linux centos

Comment: At least *pretend* to read the man page...

Comment: at least try not to be so mean - who said i didnot read the MAN page!

Comment: The answer is definitely in the man page, and you would know if you looked through the options.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
cp -Rn dir1 dir2
```

The -R means recursive (process subdirectories) and the -n means no clobber (don't overwrite).